# Change CSS of element in after Move event of Knockout sortable

Tags: css, knockout.js, knockout-sortable

I want to **change the CSS of an element once it is dragged and dropped (`afterMove` event)** to a container using the knockout sortable library. I tried getting the ID of the div containing the element and modifying its CSS in the `afterMove` event as:

`document.getElementById('container').style.backgroundColor="yellow";`

The above code does not change the color of the moved element but the very first element in the observable array of the elements. I have attached the JS fiddler of the current situation. Is their a way of accessing the `div`'s ID of the element which was moved so that only the css of that particular element is changed?

[Attached JS fiddler](http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/844/)

Comment: if you move bobby to other table you looking to change color to yellow ? or explain in functional point of view . cheers

Comment: just try this out and let me know http://jsfiddle.net/supercool/UdXr4/843/ . only bobby name has red color if it is table1 if you try to move to other table bobby color will change to yellow

Comment: @supercool Yes! I am trying to change the color to yellow of the moved element. So , if I move Bobby to the another table, it should change to yellow. Updated the fiddle in question.

Comment: check the prior comment and let me know . cheers

Comment: @supercool This won't work for me because I want to change the css for any element if it is moved to a different container, so adding conditional template binding for parent ID or index won't solve my case.

Comment: well if you try moving back bobby to first place in table one you see default red color . help me understand .

Comment: Hi supercool! The reason I want to change it in after move event is because I am sending the new position and parent of element to a server in afterMove event and want to grey out the element div till the time server sends back a success response. So, my actual problem is to change div in after move and then change it back to previous div once server approves the request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80127/discussion-between-super-cool-and-detonator123).

Comment: The fact that you need to "continue *discussion* in chat" is IMO an indication that this question is unclear. I've voted to close, because I think OP first needs to trim down the code from the fiddle to a *minimal* repro, and include it *in the question*. As it currently stands the question just does not have enough information to answer it. Otherwise this question will have minimal to no use for future visitors, especially if the link would rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a moved property to your students

```
var Student = function(id, name, gender) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = ko.observable(name);
    this.gender = gender;
    this.moved = ko.observable(false);
};
```

Bind CSS for the items to use it:

```
<div id="container" style="background-color: white; margin:4px;">
    <p data-bind="text: name, css:{two:moved}"></p>
</div>
```

Set the property after move:

```
this.updateLastAction = function(arg) {
    arg.targetParent()[arg.targetIndex].moved(true);
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UdXr4/846/